# Liferay with SSL "XXX was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from XXX" issue

Tags: tomcat, ssl, liferay, tomcat7, liferay-6

We are trying to access Liferay with `https protocol`. We have apache in front of our liferay server.
We are able to access liferay with Https. When we navigate to any page and click on Configuration, configuration pop up opens. So far so good.
Now when we navigate to any page and keep browser ideal for some time and then click on configuration we get "ran insecure content" issue 

i.e **The page at 'XYZ' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'XYZ': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS**. 
I am wondering if we are missing any configuration that needs to be done with liferay and tomcat.
Same page loading works fine but after keeping it ideal for some time it gives this issue.

Following configuration done with Liferay in portal-ext.properties:

```
web.server.protocol=https
web.server.http.port=80
web.server.https.port=443
```

Even tried by adding

```
company.security.auth.requires.https=true
session.enable.phishing.protection=false
```

And with tomcat:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
                connectionTimeout="600000"
                maxThreads="100" minSpareThreads="50" maxConnections="16384"
                socketBuffer="-1" maxKeepAliveRequests="-1"
                redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll find quite a bit of relevant information in [my latest blog article](https://www.liferay.com/web/olaf.kock/blog/-/blogs/securing-liferay-chapter-3-port-issues-and-http-https).

As you only mention the 8080 connector here, you're probably also using Apache or something else. Pay attention to the forwarding protocol (mentioned in the blog article). I'm assuming you're using http? Try AJP or the workaround that I'm naming there.

Also, when a https page contains http content, it should be easy to find out which content that is (e.g. Ctrl-i in firefox, then check the media that is loaded. Or view source and search for "http:")